# Split string by length to Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I am currently sending and splitting long lines of data to Excel. Each split prints in a new row. I want to change this from splitting at a pipe symbol in the existing data to splitting at a character length of 85, but , there are chances that at character 85 it may split a word in two. How would I tell it to split further into the data if is going to split an actual word. I know if at 85 it should also find a space after. I'm curious on what to add.

```
// Add Description
      string DescriptionSplit = srcAddOnPanel.Controls["txtProductDescAddOn" + AddRow].Text;
      string[] descriptionParts = DescriptionSplit.Split('|');
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i <= descriptionParts.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
      {
          worksheet.Rows[currentRow].Insert();    //applies the description for the default bundle row
          worksheet.Rows[currentRow].Font.Bold = false;
          worksheet.Cells[currentRow, "E"].Value = rowIndent + descriptionParts[i].Trim();
          currentRow++;
      }
```

Comment: The [Strings.InStr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47d6yh63%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method will find the position of the first space character. Couple that with the [Strings.Mid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kyd8789(v=vs.110).aspx) method so you start looking at the 85th position and add 85 to the result. Remember to concatenate a space character to the end of the string so that there is always something to find.

Comment: if you could show an example of these functions that would be awesome,

Comment: Consider using a space as your split character and building each row with the next group of words until the next word would create a row longer than 85 chars.

Comment: I can do the space delimiter but I'm just having a little difficulty grabbing it by 85 characters. Not sure if I will have to scrap the code I have and start over or just modify what I have.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this approach (Warning not fully tested)

```
int x = 85;
int y = 0;
int currentRow = 0;

// Loop until you have at least 85 char to grab
while (x + y < DescriptionSplit.Length)
{
    // Find the first white space after the 85th char
    while (x + y < DescriptionSplit.Length && 
          !char.IsWhiteSpace(DescriptionSplit[x+y]))
        x++;
    // Grab the substring and pass it to Excel for the currentRow
    InsertRowToExcel(DescriptionSplit.Substring(y, x), currentRow);

    // Prepare variables for the next loop
    currentRow++;
    y = y + x + 1;
    x = 85;
}
// Do not forget the last block
if(y < DescriptionSplit.Length)
    InsertRowToExcel(DescriptionSplit.Substring(y), currentRow);
...

void InsertRowToExcel(string toInsert, int currentRow)
{
      worksheet.Rows[currentRow].Insert();    
      worksheet.Rows[currentRow].Font.Bold = false;
      worksheet.Cells[currentRow, "E"].Value = rowIndent + toInsert.Trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VBA version that seems to work. As suggested in my comment, it separates the string by spaces and then tests whether adding a word makes the length of the current line greater than the maximum (85). As is usual with these kinds of things getting the last word to populate correctly is hard.

If this works for you it should be simple enough to modify to C#. Let me know if that's not true:

```
Sub ParseRows()
Const ROW_LENGTH As Long = 85
Dim Text As String
Dim Words As Variant
Dim RowContent As String
Dim RowNum As Long
Dim i As Long

Text = ActiveCell.Text
Words = Split(Text, " ")
RowNum = 2

For i = LBound(Words) To UBound(Words)
    If Len(RowContent & Words(i) & " ") > ROW_LENGTH Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & RowNum).Value = RowContent
        RowNum = RowNum + 1
        If i = UBound(Words) Then
            RowContent = Words(i)
        Else
            RowContent = ""
        End If
    Else
        RowContent = RowContent & Words(i) & " "
    End If
Next i
If RowContent <> "" Then ActiveSheet.Range("A" & RowNum).Value = RowContent
End Sub
```